# Declare intDef once

Tags: java, android, interface, annotations

I have read here about intDef

https://noobcoderblog.wordpress.com/2015/04/12/java-enum-and-android-intdefstringdef-annotation/

here is the example :

```
public static final int SUNDAY = 0;
public static final int MONDAY = 1;
public static final int TUESDAY = 2;
public static final int WEDNESDAY = 3;
public static final int THURSDAY = 4;
public static final int FRIDAY = 5;
public static final int SATURDAY = 6;
```

Then declare the @IntDef for these constants,

```
@IntDef({SUNDAY, MONDAY,TUESDAY,WEDNESDAY,THURSDAY,FRIDAY,SATURDAY})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
public @interface WeekDays {}
```

How do i avoid from writing the String twice ? i don't want to take chance that other developer will add A day in that scenario in one place than the annotation will reflect the change .

is this possible ?

Comment: can you explain your problem with a sample ?

Comment: Ok , lets say a constant may be added , in days it will not happen but lets say the constant are keys for shared pref ,  if a developer will want to add key he will have to add   

public static final int SOME_NEW_KEY = 6;

and here :

@IntDef({SUNDAY, MONDAY,TUESDAY,WEDNESDAY,THURSDAY,FRIDAY,SATURDAY,SOME_NEW_KEY})